# importing .png image into flash CS3

Tags: image, resize, import

While importing a .png file in Flash CS3, i noticed that it automatically gets resized. It gets imported smaller than its original size. Im importing it to the stage and not inside any symbol. Can anyone explain why this happens? Do i have to change any settings to get the original size as it is?

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because the resolution of your png is greater than 72.

you can verify the resolution of your image in photoshop by going to the menu bar and image-->image size-->resolution.

change the resolution to 72, and make sure 'resample image' is unchecked.  That is, you want to maintain the pixel dimensions of your image while downsizing the resolution.

Flash is thinking you've brought in something at 72 (as that's all it understands) and thus is rescaling it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You mean just file-> import in Flash? Or programmatically importing it?

The first question doesn't belong on SO. For the second question we need more information to be able to help you.